# How to eliminate devide by zero error in phpexcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am creating excel file using phpexcel.But in some cells i am getting devided by zero error. So i am trying to put zero instead of devided by zero error.I am trying to put zero instead of error with the following code.

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Y'.$ab,'=IFERROR(ROUND((X40*100)/X26,2),"")');
```

But cell gets empty instead of zero.

So can anyone please suggest me what i am doing wrong.suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps by putting a `0` rather than an empty string (`""`) if cell X26 is 0: `'=IFERROR(ROUND((X40*100)/X26,2),0)'` in exactly the same way you should if you were doing it in MS Excel itself

Comment: I had tried both the way

Comment: Though it's probably more efficient in Excel to test for zero rather than test for a divide by zero error: `=IF(X26=0, 0, ROUND((X40*100)/X26,2))`

Comment: This is also not working bro

Comment: I've tested both myself.... I concur that there's a bug in `=IFERROR(ROUND((X40*100)/X26,2),0)` (almost impossible to fix without complete rewrite of the calculation engine); but `=IF(X26=0, 0, ROUND((X40*100)/X26,2))` works exactly as I'd expect it to work

Comment: that same code didnot worked in my code.

Comment: is that a phpexcel version problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be a version issue... I tested against latest development branch, but it should still work the same way with 1.8.1

Comment: If it didn't work, what did you get as a result?

Comment: I am getting 0 and but when i am trying to change value of x26 manually in excel sheet its not changing the value of formula based cells of Y

Comment: You mean you're opening the file you generate in MS Excel, changing the values of cells, and it doesn't recalculate automatically?

Comment: Yes exactly i am doing the same

Comment: Then check that automatic calculation isn't disabled in your MS Excel